# Adding margins for fixed header in anchor links to another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already know how to us anchor links within the SAME page for fixed header offset issue just by adding margin to an "a" tag which is:

about.html:

```
<a href="#goto"> Section 2</a>
.
. 
.  /*some other elements here to pass through*/
.
<a class="anchor" id="goto"> </a>
```

CSS:

```
.anchor {
   margin-top: -300px;        /* Size of fixed header */
   padding-bottom: 300px; 
   display: block; 
}
```

and I also know how to goto an anchor from one page to ANOTHER page:

home.html

```
<a href="www.mysite.com/about#goto">
```

Now, i tried to use anchoring from one page to ANOTHER page using the code above which is correct where it goes to the anchored element of another page BUT the catch is that when it goes to the anchored element, the fixed header issue is still persisting, meaning that the margins from the css anchor element is not working.

I searched online and everything I see is either 1 of the 2 problems (the fixed header offset issue anchor && the goto an anchor from one page to another) but not both of the same time.

My question: Is there a way for to solve the fixed header issue from anchoring from one page to another?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide sample code in jsfiddle or codepen for easy debugging

Comment: I'm sorry about it but how do I do it in jsfiddle or codepen for multiple html pages?

Comment: I just created one for you -http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/ZOOVWa

Comment: What I mean is from multiple html page. There are two html page one is called about.html and another is home.html. What i want to know is how to go from home.html to about .html in a specific element with a fixed header offset issue.